# What are case-labeled statements and case labels?

Tags: language-agnostic, switch-statement, cyclomatic-complexity, control-flow-graph

Having read McCabe's [article](http://www.mccabe.com/pdf/mccabe-nist235r.pdf) about cyclomatic complexity, it reads:

> A less frequently occurring issue that has greater impact on
>   complexity is the distinction between “case-labeled statements” and
>   “case labels.” When several case labels apply to the same program
>   statement, this is modeled as a single decision outcome edge in the
>   control flow graph, adding one to complexity.

I do not understand - what is a "case labeled statement" and "case label"?

Do they mean if `case 1`, `case 2`, e.g. both jump to `case 3`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, McCabe is pointing out the difference in complexity between a case that directly labels a statement and a case that *falls through* to another case.

Each "case-labeled statement" adds to cyclomatic complexity, so the following example adds +3.

```
switch (arg) {
    case "foo" : System.out.println("foo");
    case "bar" : System.out.println("bar");
    case "baz" : System.out.println("baz");
}
```

A "case label" which *falls through* to another case does not add to cyclomatic complexity, so the following example adds +1.

```
switch (arg) {
    case "foo" :
    case "bar" :
    case "baz" : System.out.println("foo | bar | baz");
}
```